# I want to prompt a user for the first 5 characters of a file then have it search for the files

Tags: sh

I'm trying to write a script that will prompt the user for the first 5 charters of a file name then have it search the directories for any files that start with that. Then I want it to check to see if a folder is created with the file names and if not create one then move the files there. But if there is a directory for it already then to just move the files too the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Break it down step by step:

"prompt the user for the first 5 characters of a file name" -- you can use the shell `read` command to get the data.  Try a simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
read foo
echo "foo = $foo"
```

"if a folder is created with the file names"  -- you can use `find` to see if a file exists.  for example:

```
find . -name abcde\*
```

"But if there is a directory for it already then to just move the files too the folder." -- the command `mkdir` takes a `-p` option so that, if the directory already exists, it won't do anything.